# Class not registered. sapi5 pyttsx3 python error While creating a chatbot using python pyttsx3

Tags: python, bots, artificial-intelligence, pyttsx3

I was creating a AI but after creating the voice output function The code worked but after 1 day i rerun this same code but this error is showing.

## Python AI Output Code

```
import pyttsx3

def output(Text):
    engine = pyttsx3.init("sapi5")
    voices = engine.getProperty('voices')
    engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id) 
    engine.setProperty('rate', 135) 
    engine.setProperty('volume', 1) 
    engine.setProperty('pause', 0.5)
    print("    ")
    print(f"Output: {Text}")
    engine.say(text=Text)
    engine.runAndWait()
    print("  ")

output("")
```

## console log

`PS D:\Tess> & d:/Tess/Scripts/Activate.ps1
(Tess) PS D:\Tess> & d:/Tess/Scripts/python.exe d:/Tess/AI/output.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3_*init*_.py", line 20, in init
eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\athan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\weakref.py", line 136, in **getitem**
o = self.datakey
~~~~~~~~~^^^^^
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "d:\Tess\AI\output.py", line 2, in 
engine = pyttsx3.init()
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3_*init*_.py", line 22, in init
eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\engine.py", line 30, in **init**
self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\driver.py", line 52, in **init**
self._driver = self._module.buildDriver(weakref.proxy(self))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 30, in buildDriver
return SAPI5Driver(proxy)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 47, in **init**
self.setProperty('voice', self.getProperty('voice'))
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "D:\Tess\Lib\site-packages\pyttsx3\drivers\sapi5.py", line 90, in getProperty
return self._tts.Voice.Id
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
_ctypes.COMError: (-2147221164, 'Class not registered', (None, None, None, 0, None))
(Tess) PS D:\Tess> `

I was creating a voice bot and output i mean voice output function worked but after 1 day when I Re-ran this code it shows this error.